# How to solve"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined when adding button to tree view of Odoo"?

Tags: odoo-12

This is my code; I want to add it at the footer of the tree.

```
<tree string="Generate Payment" create="false">
    <group><field name="name"/>
    <field name="x_leave_generate"/>
    <field name="x_overtime_generate"/>
    <field name="x_attendance_generate"/> </group>
</tree>

<button name="method_name" string="Check" type="object" class="oe_button oe_form_button oe_highlight" />
```

Comment: where you want to add button in tree view?

Comment: at the bottom of the tree list

Comment: I think in list or tree view it is not possible but you can add it at top of the list view with create or edit button

Comment: but if you create tree view inside the form view then it can be

Comment: Wow!How?Let me know about that ,please!

Comment: visit this https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/can-i-add-button-to-tree-view-8155

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding button in view it must be added in view like below. You can `hader` tag if you want to display in top of tree view.

```
<tree string="Generate Payment" create="false">
    <button name="method_name" string="Check" type="object" class="oe_button oe_form_button oe_highlight" />
     <group>
         <field name="name"/> 
         <field name="x_leave_generate"/> 
         <field name="x_overtime_generate"/>
         <field name="x_attendance_generate"/> 
     </group> 
 </tree>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined. I have faced with this errors when adding like that <header>
            <button name="tree_name" string="Generate Payment" type="object" class="oe_button oe_form_button oe_highlight" /> 
               </header>
                <tree string="Generate Payment" create="false">
            <field name="name"/>
                <field name="x_leave_generate"/>
                <field name="x_overtime_generate"/>
                <field name="x_attendance_generate"/>